# One Wire Problem

Tags: embedded, pic, pic18, 1wire

I need your qualified help!
I'm programing in C++, using a PIC 18F87J50 and trying to connect DS18B20 at my H0 Port!

I think my underlying programing is correct so.... the problem I have (think I have),
is when performing a ROM Command, I'm searching for the 64-bit ROM CODE.

The first byte should tell me what family the component belongs to (28h).
The next 48 bits should give me a uniq serial for just that component.
The last one is used for a CRC.

Am I thinking right when doing like this:

```
void Device_ID( uint8_t command ){
    uint8_t ROM_CODE[8]; // 1 byte CRC, 6 bytes SERIAL, 1 byte Family code
    uint8_t loop;
    static char container[8];

    OW_reset_pulse();
    OW_write_byte( command );

    for(loop = 0; loop < 8; loop++)     // 1 byte in per time = 64-bits
    {
        ROM_CODE[loop] = OW_read_byte(); 
    }

    HexToStrWithZeros(ROM_CODE[0], container);
    Display_Cls();
    Display_StringAt ("Family Code: ",5,6);
    Display_Buffer (container);
}
```

If I ask for the code in ROM_CODE[1-6] I should get the uniq number?? should'nt I??

Kind Regards!

Comment: What's inside HexToStrWithZeros()?

Comment: Hi Sharptooth!!

This is in Hex:

void HexToStrWithZeros(uint16_t input, char *output)
{
 static const rom uint8_t digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

 uint8_t i = 2;
 output += i;
 *output = '\0';
 do
 {

  *--output = digits[input & 15];
  input >>= 4;
 }
 while(--i);
}

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910128/1wire-problem-in-detail/1963928#1963928 for some DS18B20 code,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the best way to access the serial number is probably to copy it into a separate buffer using [strncpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncpy/).

```
#include <string.h>

...

char family;
char serial[7]; // Extra byte for null terminator
char checksum;

...

family = ROM_CODE[0];

strncpy(serial, &ROM_CODE[1], 6);
serial[6] = '\0';

checksum = ROM_CODE[7];

...
```

The `&ROM_CODE[1]` is there to fetch the address of the 2nd element in `ROM_CODE`. `ROM_CODE+1` may also work, but my C is a touch rusty.

The null ('\0') is added at the end as C uses [null-terminated strings](http://chortle.ccsu.edu/AssemblyTutorial/Chapter-20/ass20_2.html). This will make sure it's compatible with C library routines and commonly used C idioms.

You could also access it directly from the array. But that'll be harder to work with and unlikely to be worth it unless you **really** need that 6 bytes of memory.

Depending on how sophisticated your app is, you may want to wrap this in a class. Pass the 8 character buffer to the constructor and then use methods such as `getFamily()` / `getSerial()` to retrieve the information you want.

For a very simple app though, that's a whole lot of extra code to simplify something that's already very manageable.

Comment: Thank you for replying!

My Programmer's Notepad complaining about "suspicious pointer conversion" when doing this: strncpy(serial, &ROM_CODE[1], 6); Is that a problem?

/Thanks

Comment: Oh... I just tried your suggestion and the resault was the same... implying that Im doing something wrong before this step.. :(

Comment: It might be worth learning to use GDB then. It'll allow you to watch whats happening more closely.

Comment: GDB... what is that? 

The thing going wrong here, is that I will only recieve a 64-bit number that is all "one´s" I print to the screen FFFFFFF.... and so on.

My device should give me an uniq number in the ROM_CODE[] that isnt full of one's

Comment: Hm... I think my problem now more or less lies in the functions before this function... so this question is answered for!

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that should allow you to read the device ID.  I think your code was running to fast here is some code that I used to interface with the DS18B20.

```
/****************************************************************************
* temperature.h
****************************************************************************/

#ifndef TEMP_H
#define TEMP_H

extern double read_temp ( void );
extern   void start_temp( void );
extern   void Device_ID ( void );

#endif

/****************************************************************************
* temperature.c
****************************************************************************/

void     reset_ow(void);
void     write_ow(uint8_t  b);
uint8_t  read_ow (void);

#define OW_TEMP_SIG LATHbits.LATH0
#define OW_TEMP_TRIS TRISHbits.TRISH0
#define OW_TEMP_SIG_IN PORTHbits.RH0
#define DIR_OUT 0
#define DIR_IN 1


void Device_ID( void )
{
    uint8_t loop; 
   uint8_t family; 
   uint8_t checksum; 
   uint8_t ROM_CODE[8];         // 1 byte CRC, 6 bytes SERIAL, 1 byte Family code

   reset_ow();
   write_ow(0x33); // READ ROM COMMAND DS18B20

    for(loop = 0; loop < 8; loop++) // 1 byte in per time = 64-bits
    {
        ROM_CODE[loop] = read_ow();
    }

    family = ROM_CODE[0];
    checksum = ROM_CODE[7];

  // add extra code to handle code
}

void start_temp(void) 
{
   uint8_t i;

   OW_TEMP_SIG=1;
   OW_TEMP_TRIS=DIR_OUT;
   for ( i=0;i<100;i++)
   {
       Delay_us(100);
   }
   reset_ow();
   write_ow(0xcc); // skip rom
   write_ow(0x44); // start t conv
}

double read_temp(void) 
{
   double temp=0;
   S16 itemp;

   reset_ow();
   write_ow(0xcc); // skip rom
   write_ow(0xbe); // read scratch pad
   itemp=read_ow();
   itemp|=(S16)read_ow()<<8;

   temp = itemp*(0.0625);
   OW_TEMP_TRIS=DIR_IN;
   OW_TEMP_SIG=1;
   return temp; 
}


void reset_ow(void)
{
   OW_TEMP_TRIS=DIR_OUT;
   OW_TEMP_SIG=0;
   Delay_us(250);
   Delay_us(250);
   OW_TEMP_TRIS=DIR_IN;
   OW_TEMP_SIG=1;
   Delay_us(250);
   Delay_us(250);
}

void write_ow(uint8_t b)
{
   uint8_t i;

   OW_TEMP_SIG=1;
   OW_TEMP_TRIS=DIR_OUT;
   for ( i=0;i<8;i++)
   {
      OW_TEMP_SIG=0;
      if ( b & 0x01 )
      {
         Delay_us(10);
         OW_TEMP_SIG=1;
      }
      Delay_us(70);
      OW_TEMP_SIG=1;
      Delay_us(10);
      b >>= 1;
   }
   OW_TEMP_TRIS=DIR_IN;
   OW_TEMP_SIG=1;
}

uint8_t read_ow(void)
{
   uint8_t b=0;
   uint8_t m;
   uint8_t i;

   m=1;
   for ( i=0;i<8;i++)
   {
      OW_TEMP_SIG=1;
      OW_TEMP_TRIS=DIR_OUT;
      OW_TEMP_SIG=0;        
      Delay_us(8);
      OW_TEMP_TRIS=DIR_IN;
      OW_TEMP_SIG=1;
      Delay_us(15);

      if ( 1 == OW_TEMP_SIG_IN )
      {
         b |= m;
      }
      m <<=1;
      Delay_us(60);
   }
   OW_TEMP_TRIS=DIR_IN;
   OW_TEMP_SIG=1;
   return b;
}
```