# 1wire problem in detail

Tags: embedded, pic, pic18, 1wire

I have defined these functions below, and when I ask Device_ID function for example of
the family code, I only get FF (should be 28), acctually I get both the family code, 48-bit serial, and the crc 8 bit to be all "ones". It seems like the detect slave device function works as it should.... If i connect the slave he say's I am here, and if i take it away... no device present. I also have a 5kohm pull-up at the 1wire.

And I dont have a clue why my Device_ID dont work, so my question is why doesnt it work!? can u see anything wrong within this code (Im using a PIC 18F87J50 and one DS18B20):

My statement in Main:

```
     OSCTUNEbits.PLLEN = 1;

 Init_Registers();
 Init_Settings();
 Init_Ports();
 Init_Glcd();

 Detect_Slave_Device();
 Device_ID( 0x33 );
```

Used functions:

```
    void Detect_Slave_Device(void){ 
 uint8_t value;
 OW_reset_pulse();
 if (OW_reset_pulse())
 {
  Display_Cls();
  Display_StringAt("No Device Present!",5,6);
  Delay_1sec();
  Delay_1sec();
 } else {
  Display_Cls();
  Display_StringAt("Device Present!",5,6);
  Delay_1sec();
  Delay_1sec(); }}
```

---

```
   uint8_t OW_reset_pulse(void){
 uint8_t presence_detect;

   drive_OW_low();     // Drive the bus low

  Delay_us(200);     // Delay at least 480 microsecond (us)
 Delay_us(200);
 Delay_us(85);  

  drive_OW_high ();      // Release the bus
         // Here should the client drive low
 Delay_us(50);     // Delay 50 microsecond (us)

 presence_detect = read_OW(); // Sample for presence pulse from slave

  Delay_us(200);       // Delay 435 microsecond (us)
 Delay_us(200);
 Delay_us(35);  

 drive_OW_high ();       // Release the bus

 return presence_detect;}
```

---

```
    void drive_OW_low (void){
 LATHbits.LATH0 = 0;
 TRISHbits.TRISH0 = 0; }// Output
```

---

```
    void drive_OW_high (void){
 LATHbits.LATH0 = 0;
 TRISHbits.TRISH0 = 1;} // Input
```

---

```
    uint8_t read_OW (void){
 unsigned char read_data=0;

 TRISHbits.TRISH0 = 1;

  if (1 == PORTHbits.RH0)
   read_data = 1;
  else  
  read_data = 0;

 return read_data;}
```

And now some ofthe important device_id:

```
    void Device_ID( uint8_t command ){
 uint8_t loop, family, checksum, ROM_CODE[8];   // 1 byte CRC, 6 bytes SERIAL, 1 byte Family code
 static char container[1];

 OW_reset_pulse();
 OW_write_byte( 0x33 );   // READ ROM COMMAND DS18B20

 for(loop = 0; loop < 9; loop++) // 1 byte in per time = 64-bits
 {
  ROM_CODE[loop] = OW_read_byte();
 }

 family = ROM_CODE[1];
 checksum = ROM_CODE[8];
 And so on = Print MY VALUES ->
```

---

```
   void OW_write_byte (uint8_t write_data){
 uint8_t loop;

 for (loop = 0; loop < 8; loop++)
 {
  OW_write_bit(write_data & 0x01);  //Sending LS-bit first
  write_data >>= 1;     // shift the data byte for the next bit to send
 } }
```

---

```
   void OW_write_bit (uint8_t write_bit){
 if (write_bit)       // Write 1 time slot
 { 
  Brakepoint();     // 1 us
  //writing a bit '1'
  drive_OW_low();     // Drive the bus low
  Delay_us(6);     // Delay 6 microsecond (us)
  drive_OW_high ();      // Release the bus
  Delay_us(64);;     // Delay 64 microsecond (us)
 }
 else        // Write 0 time slot
 {
  Brakepoint();     // 1 us
  //writing a bit '0'
  drive_OW_low();     // Drive the bus low
  Delay_us(65);     // Delay 65 microsecond (us)
  drive_OW_high ();      // Release the bus
  Delay_us(10);     // Delay 10 microsecond for recovery (us)
 }}
```

---

```
   uint8_t OW_read_byte (void)
 uint8_t loop, result=0;

 for (loop = 0; loop < 8; loop++)
 {

  result >>= 1;     // shift the result to get it ready for the next bit to receive
  if (OW_read_bit())
   result |= 0x80;   // if result is one, then set MS-bit
 }
 return result;     }
```

---

```
   uint8_t OW_read_bit (void){
 uint8_t read_data;       // Reading a bit 
 Brakepoint();       // 1 us
 drive_OW_low();       // Drive the bus low
 Delay_us(6);       // delay 6 microsecond (us)
 drive_OW_high ();        // Release the bus
 Delay_us(9);       // delay 9 microsecond (us)

 read_data = read_OW();     //Read the status of OW_PIN

 Delay_us(55);       // delay 55 microsecond (us) 
 return read_data;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fault was not the code it self, I tried to connect it to a digital port with a RC filter, a small conductor of 10nf and a resistor of 1k ohm.

I did not know this until later. Thanks for the response, it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that I wrote for a PIC18 to read a DS18B20.

```
/****************************************************************************
* temperature.h
****************************************************************************/

#ifndef TEMP_H
#define TEMP_H

extern double read_temp(void) ;
extern void start_temp(void);

#endif

/****************************************************************************
* temperature.c
****************************************************************************/

void     reset_ow(void);
void     write_ow(uint8_t  b);
uint8_t  read_ow (void);

#define OW_TEMP_SIG LATHbits.LATH0
#define OW_TEMP_TRIS TRISHbits.TRISH0
#define OW_TEMP_SIG_IN PORTHbits.RH0
#define DIR_OUT 0
#define DIR_IN 1

void start_temp(void) 
{
   uint8_t i;

   OW_TEMP_SIG=1;
   OW_TEMP_TRIS=DIR_OUT;
   for ( i=0;i<100;i++)
   {
       Delay_us(100);
   }
   reset_ow();
   write_ow(0xcc); // skip rom
   write_ow(0x44); // start t conv
}

double read_temp(void) 
{
   double temp=0;
   S16 itemp;

   reset_ow();
   write_ow(0xcc); // skip rom
   write_ow(0xbe); // read scratch pad
   itemp=read_ow();
   itemp|=(S16)read_ow()<<8;

   temp = itemp*(0.0625);
   OW_TEMP_TRIS=DIR_IN;
   OW_TEMP_SIG=1;
   return temp; 
}


void reset_ow(void)
{
   OW_TEMP_TRIS=DIR_OUT;
   OW_TEMP_SIG=0;
   Delay_us(250);
   Delay_us(250);
   OW_TEMP_TRIS=DIR_IN;
   OW_TEMP_SIG=1;
   Delay_us(250);
   Delay_us(250);
}

void write_ow(uint8_t b)
{
   uint8_t i;

   OW_TEMP_SIG=1;
   OW_TEMP_TRIS=DIR_OUT;
   for ( i=0;i<8;i++)
   {
      OW_TEMP_SIG=0;
      if ( b & 0x01 )
      {
         Delay_us(10);
         OW_TEMP_SIG=1;
      }
      Delay_us(70);
      OW_TEMP_SIG=1;
      Delay_us(10);
      b >>= 1;
   }
   OW_TEMP_TRIS=DIR_IN;
   OW_TEMP_SIG=1;
}

uint8_t read_ow(void)
{
   uint8_t b=0;
   uint8_t m;
   uint8_t i;

   m=1;
   for ( i=0;i<8;i++)
   {
      OW_TEMP_SIG=1;
      OW_TEMP_TRIS=DIR_OUT;
      OW_TEMP_SIG=0;        
      Delay_us(8);
      OW_TEMP_TRIS=DIR_IN;
      OW_TEMP_SIG=1;
      Delay_us(15);

      if ( 1 == OW_TEMP_SIG_IN )
      {
         b |= m;
      }
      m <<=1;
      Delay_us(60);
   }
   OW_TEMP_TRIS=DIR_IN;
   OW_TEMP_SIG=1;
   return b;
}
```